# (Some) custom fonts won't import through CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, sass

So I am currently trying to import a variety of Avenir Next LT Pro fonts, which I have local access to, into a web application.

I can successfully use the italic, bold, and regular versions with no problem - but the Demi font option does not work.

I import them using SASS as so:

```
  @mixin font($family, $path) {
    font-family: $family;
    @font-face {
        font-family: $family;
        src: url("../assets/font/"+$path) format('opentype');
    }
}

.avenirNext-italic {
    @include font('AvenirNext-italic', "AvenirNext/AvenirNextLTPro-It.otf");
}
.avenirNext-demi {

    @include font('AvenirNext-demi', "AvenirNext/AvenirNextLTPro-Demi.otf");
}
.avenirNext-bold {
    @include font('AvenirNext-bold', "AvenirNext/AvenirNextLTPro-Bold.otf");
}
.avenirNext-regular {
    @include font('AvenirNext-regular', "AvenirNext/AvenirNextLTPro-Regular.otf");
}
```

Why won't Demi work? all of the others I can use with no issues.

Comment: Are the other fonts also .otf?

Comment: yes. i tried a .ttf for demi as well, with no success

Comment: Does the browser console give any errors about not being able to load files? If you open the generated CSS and copy-paste the path to the demi variant into the browser, does it load the file?

Comment: there are no errors - i am confident in the paths of the font files because 3 fonts in the same directory with the same naming conventions load and work in the browser with no problem.

I have gone letter by letter through the spelling - there are no errors there.